# Приложение на платформе .NET Framework 1.0

Tags: windows, фреймворк

Добрый день.

Необходимо создать Windows-приложение (на C#) для его запуска на Windows XP и Windows Server 2003 (т.е. приложение предусматривает максимальную гибкость между ОС). Насколько известно, то на нем установлен по умолчанию именно `.NET Framework 1.0` или `.NET Framework 1.1` в зависимости от Service Pack: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B6.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.9E.D0.A1

В Visual Studio Community 2015 самая ранняя версия платформы, которая доступна при создании проекта, только 2.0.

**Вопрос:** Существует ли способ создать в VS Windows-приложение, которое поддерживалось бы на чистом Windows XP и Windows Server 2003? Или, возможно, существует другой способ унифицировать приложение под самые ранние ОС?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы не будете использовать C# и статически слинкуете приложение, оно работать будет и на XP и на Win7. Возможно и на более ранних/поздних, не проверял.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Если не трудно, в двух словах объясните, что Вы имели в виду под словами "статически слинкуете приложение".

Comment: Прекратите насиловать труп! Тащите с собой redist .NET Fx 4 и пишите нём. Вот вам [таблицы совместимости](http://stackoverflow.com/a/198925/276994).

Comment: Я имел в виду "статическую линковку", в двух словах. Не в двух - когда приложение не зависит ни от каких DLL, кроме системных.

Comment: @VladD Ну, в этих таблицах показана просто совместимость ОС и платформ (эта же информация расписана по ссылке, которую я вставил в вопрос). А мне нужно быть готовым к тому, что мое приложение будет запускаться в ОС, где установлен 1.0 или 1.1 фреймворк.

Comment: @vitaliklibra: Ну я ж говорю, тащите с собой redistributable, ставьте .NET 4 при инсталляции. Запускаться без инсталляции не разрешайте.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Я бы с радостью отказался от DLL, кроме системных, да вот только мне как раз нужно использовать 3 библиотеки не системные. Теоретически, они должны отработать и на платформе 1.0, но! Я проверил: при одном и том же составе сборки, но при разных изначально выбираемых версиях платформы при создании проекта, приложение НЕ запускается на ОС, где платформа ниже той, на которой компилировалась сборка.

Comment: @VladD, как бы да, это вариант я рассматривал, но хотелось спросить знатоков, существует ли такая возможность, чтобы использовать 1.0 платформу и студию. На просторах интернета ничего подобного найти не смог. А найти решение надо...

Comment: @vitaliklibra: Понял. Тогда подождём, пока скажут что-то толковое.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Вы имеете в виду .NET Native?

Comment: @VladD, Ваше решение тоже толковое) Но это "замена одного костыля на другой". Тут надо копать глубже. Хотя, подозреваю, что это и будет единственным, а потому и подходящим решением.

Comment: @VladD я имею в виду под "другой способ унифицировать приложение под самые ранние ОС" отказ от .NET и статическую линковку.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: А, я не прочитал «Если вы не будете использовать C#». Кстати, статическая линковка тоже требует подходящего для древних систем рантайма, так что придётся найти достаточно старый компилятор.

Comment: Я в 2015 или 2013 студии писал софт и оно успешно на XP работало. 2008я точно не имеет никаких проблем с совместимостью

Comment: @vitaliklibra для компиляции под 1.0/1.1 придется искать старую версию студии. Новая умеет собирать только под 2.0 и выше

Comment: PashaPash, VladD, ВладимирМартьянов - Спасибо за ответы.